# freeze header or sticky header on website sp 2013

Tags: 2013, global-navigation

I am working on SP2013 & I want to apply freeze header or sticky header in my site. I have tried spoodoo header but it doesn't work.

Can anyone give me idea how to get output?

I have tried to using `position:fixed` but it overlaps the page !!
thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to fix the header of the List Columns ?

Comment: no , I want the global navigation to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS on your Page if you want for single Page or on your Master Page if you want it for the whole site

```
div#DeltaTopNavigation { position: fixed; margin-top: -10px; }
```

Comment: ok , I will try it out

Comment: nope , not working

Comment: What's the problem you are facing now ? SP 2013 or 2010 ?

Comment: the header goes after applying that :p